# Show item in center of gridview android

Tags: android, gridview

[image]

I am designing an app like foody, i have 5 item, put it in a gridview and set **android:numColumns="3"** . but in the second line, the items doesn't appear in center of the gridview row. i have tried some solution but nothing changed. Is anyone here used to deal with it, please give me your solution.

Comment: It's better to use `recyclerView` with `gridLayoutManager` where you can set the span size for each item

Comment: thank you but it doesn't work, do you have any others solution?

Comment: i tried again with some more changes, and it worked, thank you very much